# React page is not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, mern

Ive 2 pages connected to app.js
one is home.js and second is compiler.js
both are rendered using react router home is perfectly rendering and when i move to compiler.js the page loads and no content is showing up

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6czXN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hznYM.png)

can anyone explain whats going on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is it the space in the path

<Route path="/Compiler/: roomId" element={}>

Try
<Route path="/Compiler/:roomId" element={}>